# Sharing user generated image to Twitter via Twitter Cards

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, twitter

I'm trying to implement a button that, when clicked, shares a dynamically-created image on Twitter. I currently have functionality that sends my image on the page to imgur to be hosted, and returns a URL to that image-- that's working great.

I'm trying to send that image URL to the `<meta name="twitter:image">` via jQuery in order to share it on Twitter, but nothing shows up in the tweet that is generated. Also, when I check

```
$('meta[name="twitter:image"]').attr("content");
```

in the console, I get the empty string I originally assigned it--the image URL that is returned from imgur never gets assigned there.

Here are my meta tags:

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@mytwitterhandle">
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@mytwitterhandle">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="mytitle">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="mycontent">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="">
```

This is my JavaScript that generates the image, sends it to imgur, and returns the URL:

```
$('body').on('click','.twitter-share-button',function(e){
   var svg = $("#svg")[0];

svg.toDataURL("image/png", {
    callback: function(img) {
    var img = img.replace("data:image/png;base64,", "");
    var imgurTitle = $("meta[property='og:title']").attr("content");

    $.ajax({ 
        url: 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image',
        headers: {'Authorization': 'Client-ID ***********'},
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'image': img, 'type': 'base64', 'title': imgurTitle},
        success: function(result) { 
          NEWIMAGEURL = result.data.link;
           $('meta[name=twitter:image]').attr("content", NEWIMAGEURL);

      },
      error: function () {
           console.log('error');
          }
    });

  }
})

e.preventDefault();
});
```

And this is what I have in my HTML for the button:

```
<a class='twitter-share-button' 
      href='https://twitter.com/intent/tweet'>
    Tweet</a>
              <button id='note'>(enable pop-ups)</button>
```

Any advice/guidance would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Did you check the console for errors? What do you see in the network tab?

Comment: No errors in the console, and everything looks normal in the Network tab...although it doesn't look like there is any activity related to the image url...which makes me thing the error is in how I'm actually trying to send this image to Twitter..I'm not sure if this is even how you are supposed to do it.